# Excel: Increment column letter

Tags: excel

I have an excel workbook with two worksheets.
On one sheet I have data horizontal and my second sheet I have data vertical.
I want on sheet 2 to drag down my reference from sheet 1 data.
I am looking to have column increase not my row increase? Makes sense?
I try to "equal" the cell i want from sheet 1. However when I drag down my reference goes down instead of across.
Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

Comment: Are you just trying to transpose the data from sheet 1 to sheet 2?

Comment: Yes.
But I dont want to have to "copy and paste special" with my data every time. I was hoping for a formula to reference back to sheet 1 and I could just drag down in Sheet 2. Changing the column letter by one each time.

Comment: @BigBen is right why not use transpose?

Comment: The TRANSPOSE function.

Comment: How does Transpose increase the column letter? Also, when I drag down on Sheet 2 in my column, how would that reference my rown increament in sheet 1?
I need to upload my problem, how do i do that? Soz, Im new here.

Comment: It doesn't increase the column letter. It converts a vertical range to a horizontal range, and vice versa. Try it, and if it's not what you want, you can also use INDEX.

Comment: Ahh yes, I've heard of Index. Can I use that with Transpose?

Comment: I have added sheet1. Doesnt allow my to embed 2 images in my original post.
But on sheet 2, I have
Budget Forecast Actual
And on the vertical I have months.
I want to return the data from sheet1 to sheet2 but dragging it down. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Try adding the 2nd screenshot now.

Comment: Added second screen shot of Sheet2. With reference back to Sheet1

Comment: You can use transpose to do this, but understanding and using INDEX is probably the better way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually: Use Index. The syntax is Index(range,row number, column number)

If you want to transpose a range in Sheet1 to Sheet2, you can use

```
=Index(Sheet1!$A$1:$J$10,column(A1),row(A1))
```

Copy across and down.

See how the row argument uses the column command and the column argument uses the row command.  That means in the starting cell A1, the INDEX formula will return the column number 1 for the row argument and the row 1 for the column argument, i.e.

```
=Index(Sheet1!$A$1:$J$10,1,1)
```

Copy the formula to row 2 and the reference in the column argument will refer to `Row(A2)`, so the formula will translate to

```
=Index(Sheet1!$A$1:$J$10,1,2)
```

i.e. it will return the value from the second COLUMN of the index range. See the screenshot for a result. Change the Index range to your desired source.

[image]

Comment: @AaronR If you found the answer useful then please accept the answer so that we can know problem is solved.

Comment: How do I do that? Teylyn's answer was exact. Thanks!